# pip fails to install python toolkit (python 2.7, windows 7)

Tags: python-2.7, pip, package, lapack

i am fairly new to python. My OS is windows 7 and i am using python 2.7 (i downloaded python(x,y)). Now pip fails to install the tool kit  igakit and encounter the following problem:

```
$gfortran.lib(backtrace.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __Unwind_GetIpInfo referenced in function _trace_function

$gfortran.lib(backtrace.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __Unwind_Backtrace referenced in function __gfortran_backtrace
```

I roamed the internet for a while and this is what i already checked:
- i have MS Visual 2008 Express
- pip seems to work fine otherwise (upgraded numpy without problem)
- pip, setuptools, gcc are all up to date
- as far as i can see my Path variables seem to be fine

How do i tackle this problem?

Since this is my first time asking these things online, feel free to give me some hints on which informations i need to provide.

Best regards

EDIT

So , i wanted to upgrade the more common SciPy and ran into this problem: i am missing Lapack, Atlas and blas libraries. Does anybody know an instruction/tutorial for the installation of lapack etc. that is comprehensible to a newbie?

Answer (score 0):

for the blas/lapack part:

get the blas and lapack libraries (links in comments, since I don't have enough reps to post more than 2 links), or if you have 64-bit python, then the 64-bit blas and lapack libraries, copy them into C:\Python27\Lib (or wherever your python installation is located). the compiler should find them there.

for the other errors:

i encountered the same problem, and did not manage to find and answer yet. if you have got this far, then the VC compiler, the fortan compiler, pip and setuptools are probably OK.

if you are not insisting on building with pip, you can install a pre-built scipy from [Christoph Gohlke's website](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy). download the wheel (.whl) for your configuration (cp27, 32 or 64 bit), and then install it from pip, by typing the following command to cmd (cd to the folder containing the file first):

```
pip install scipy-0.17.0-cp27-none-win32.whl
```

or ...win_am64.whl. Choose 32/64 bit version based on your Python installation, NOT on Windows 7. So if you have 64-bit Windows, but 32-bit pyhton, go for the 32-bit wheel (or blas/lapack, if you are patient enough :) )

have fun!

Comment: 32-bit [blas](https://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/libraries/VisualStudio/3.6.0/Dynamic-MINGW/Win32/libblas.lib) and [lapack](https://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/libraries/VisualStudio/3.6.0/Dynamic-MINGW/Win32/liblapack.lib)

Comment: 64-bit [blas](https://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/libraries/VisualStudio/3.6.0/Dynamic-MINGW/Win64/libblas.lib) and [lapack](https://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/libraries/VisualStudio/3.6.0/Dynamic-MINGW/Win64/liblapack.lib)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Anaconda, you can download 2 packs:
mingw,libpython.
Maybe with mingw

> fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'gfortran.lib'

will disappear